# In WSO2 how to get Domain name after authenticate from identity provider like Facebook and Gmail

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am new in using wso2 identity server.

**My question is:**

Step-1: I using travelocity.com application.

Step-2: I have create two identity provider For Gmail and Facebook.

Step-3: Then i have create one Service Provider.

In Service Provider select "Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration".

In "Authentication Type" select "Advanced Configuration" and mapped "Local Authenticators" and "Federated Authenticators".

In Local Authenticators i have select "basic".

In "Federated Authenticators" i have select both "FacebookIDP" and "GmailIDP".

Step 4: But after Authentication from "Facebook" or "Gmail" i have to check that From which Identity Provider i have logged in travelocity.com either by Facebook or Gmail.

So i need their domain-name or anything else which identify whether it was Facebook account or Gmail account by which i logged in travelocity.com.

After authentication how i will find from which domain i got authenticate if both identity provider(Facebook and Gmail) having same email id. Because use of that domain i will check my database is this domain can i have permission or not to authenticate.

So How to get domain name after authentication from Focebook or Gmail account using wso2 identity server?

Answer (score 0):

[image]check **Always send back the authenticated list of identity providers** from Service provider -> Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGBYf.png). By checking above you will get list of authenticated idps as a JWT in AuthenticatedIdPs param. You can use https://jwt.io/ to decode it. Have a look below sample. Also have a look [2].

{
  "iss": "wso2",
  "exp": 15526220351213000,
  "iat": 1552622035121,
  "idps": [
    {
      "idp": "LOCAL",
      "authenticator": "BasicAuthenticator"
    }
  ]
}

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGBYf.png) https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Local+and+Outbound+Authentication+for+a+Service+Provider

[2] [Return Home Realm Identifier WSO2 Identity Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46887680/return-home-realm-identifier-wso2-identity-server)

Comment: I already checked that settings. How can I access that JWT token exactly, could you please describe more? How can i get these parameters?

Comment: for SAML I have attached the screen

Comment: where you have attached the screen with SAML? Can you provide me the link

Comment: How will i get these screen which you added?

Comment: am  confused about screen shot How will i get these screens and on which url i get these value? please more clarify am new to work with wso2 server

Comment: What is the protocol you are using for authentication? Also when you push question to stack overflow please mention complete story or use case with steps you have followed

Comment: I have updated my question please suggest me something. My only question is after logged in through identity provider i need their domain name  like "https://www.facebook.com" or "https://www.gmail.com"